# FCM Cloud Messaging SDK no Vibrate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my phone on silent mode, notification vibrate working well. But when I am not on silent mode, sound working well but the vibration isn't working. I want to get vibrate when on silent mode or not on silent mode

I test with FCM SDK v10.2.0 until v11.2.0

I use "notification" and "data" payload

Comment: What is question Hasan?

Comment: how I fix it? I want to always vibrate when on silent mode or not on slient mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask to google and they recommend me to use data payload only instead of data and notification payload if I want to custom my own notification.

Just for information. I use data and notification payload because on several phone, its not receive the payload

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

//vibrate
builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }); 

//light
builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use notification and data payload